# adcash removal assistance needed

Tags: 14.04, malware

help me to get rid of adcash pop-ups, please. I thought that ubuntu is a more or less virus-free system (

please,in case when u answering, try to be as thorough as it's possible, because I installed ubuntu just a month ago.

Comment: Ubuntu has nothing to do with adcash pop-ups. It's not a virus topic.

Comment: so, what u think, why everytime when I open a random page in case of every random click in a random place within the browser I get this da mn adcash pop-up, which lead me to various addvertisments?

Comment: in the first place why did you install it? Don't you know that adkash is an advertisement service it pushes as many ads/pop-ups as possible. Look even here http://malwaretips.com/blogs/adcash-com-removal/ how to remove it from a browser. To scan and delete suspicous files within Ubuntu you can use ClamAV https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV

Comment: You can try change your dns to like google DNS.. I have same issue and I changed DNS  an than pop-ups doesnt open now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, now I can answer to this question by myself. So, this tipe of virus is situated not in the PC itself (may be it can create some suspisious files in various directories, but even if u remove them every time it doesn't mean that the problem is solved). It's just changeing something within the router, making some kind  of new DNS (in my case it started with 185.) and this is the main reason of pop-ups. By the way, I didn't instal anything suspisios, the infection was from clicking suspisious webpages, adds, I don't know.

And by the way, because of the abovementioned this infection affects also
via Wi-Fi.

So one have just to contact to Internet provider's support team, ask them to change that DNS into the provider's DNS. Or u can hard reset your router if u know how to do this and have all required information (if you know, for instance, the DNS of your provider).

Just after that antiviruses and PC or browser cleaning can help.

I appreciate all answers,thank you all who wanted to help.

Comment: I would also say that most of the answers in the net is just cheating peep: everybody tries to sell something, to force you to install some products into your PC, etc... da mn cheaters
just look at this one's name: adcash powerful remuval :D

Answer (score 0):

Navigate the menus;
Applications->Systems->Ubuntu Software Center,
Search for ClamTk, install.
if it doesn't run automatically, Applications->Accessories-> ClamTk,
Do a recursive directory scan. 
while it is true linux is less vulnerable, it is not invulnerable. Because we are less prominent, we are less of a target. This is security through obscurity. Not a good thing.
I ran ClamTk last night and it found a Trojan lurking about.
Good luck.

Comment: tyvm. hope it will help

Comment: nope, it doesn't work ( clamtk found like 180 treats but I think those were from windows files, driver packs, etc.

Comment: surfing internet all the day, trying to find something that could be useful. seems very few people have an imagination how to deal with it in windows and nobody talk about ubuntu. nobody have clue what could be helpful?

Comment: @newbie point ClamAV to scan a directory use for example `clamscan -rio ~/` command it will scan your Home Dir e.g. which will also print the paths where the virus or infected file at but not to think or to guess. Then you can manually delete it by going to its location.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I disabled all the extensions I had installed and restarted Firefox and the problem was solved. No need to install any tool for adware removal. So please try to remove unwanted extensions (or ones you are unsure about) to solve the issue.